# Should I pass command line arguments to MPI_Init or not?

Tags: c++, c, mpi

When writing MPI 3.0 code, should I pass `argc` and `argv` to the `MPI_Init` call or not, and why?

EDIT: Since Bill Barth's answer raised some questions I want to make some remarks:

- Passing `argc`/`argv` is not required since MPI 1.1.
- The question is specifically about why should/shouldn't one pass `argc`/`argv` (*why shouldn't you* is then not really an answer).
- Still, sometimes you cannot pass `argc`/`argv` to `MPI_Init` (writing a library that uses static initialization to start MPI if main is outside your control and MPI is an implementation detail).

EDIT2: The question *why wouldn't you use `MPI_Init(argc, argv)`* has come too often now. Some reasons:

- Doing it for the sake of compatibility with older/non-compliant/compliant MPI < 1.1 implementations is not possible since if you are using MPI2 or MPI3 features those won't work anyways.
- `MPI_Init()` initializes the MPI runtime in the same way as `MPI_Init(argc, argv)`
- `MPI_Init(argc, argv)` removes arguments passed to the MPI run-time from `argc`, and `argv` *and* initializes MPI. AFAIK it is the only way to clean `argc` and `argv` so if you need these to have no MPI arguments you need to use it.
- `MPI_Init()` can be used in more situations that `MPI_Init(argc, argv)`. For example your library using MPI as an implementation detail can test if MPI is initialized, and if not, call `MPI_Init()` and the right thing will happen. Your user doesn't know that you are using mpi, doesn't need to pass `argc`, `argv` to your library, doesn't need to change their main (in case it is taking no arguments) to use your library....

Comment: I don't follow why BillBarth's response doesn't answer your question. The "why wouldn't you" part looks like it sums up the gist of his response, which describes what happened with previous MPI implementations, and why not passing arguments could cause problems. Perhaps you're looking for something more definitive?

Comment: @GeoffOxberry The problem with the _why wouldn't you_ answer is that it is as good as a _why would you_ answer. Since all MPI implementations supporting MPI > 1.1 have to offer the alternative `MPI_Init()` which _has to_ correctly get the arguments you pass to `mpirun`/`mpiexec` _somehow_ (it is unspecified how), and since `MPI_Init()` can be used in more situations than `MPI_Init(argc, argv)` (and without workarounds), I don't really see the point on using `MPI_Init(argc, argv)` if you are targeting MPI 3.0.

Comment: Compatibility with MPI implementations supporting MPI < 1.1 is not possible anyways if you have to use MPI 2.0 or MPI 3.0 features.

Comment: You're still missing my basic point. The MPI distribution cannot tell at execution time whether your MPI_Init passes NULLs or not, so it probably puts stuff on the command line. If you don't pass argc and argv, then MPI_Init cannot edit them to remove its additions, therefore your code will have to be robust to spurious command-line arguments from MPI. Therefore, why take the risk of having to deal with an arbitrary and perhaps conflicting set of arguments when you can pass them to MPI_Init and get back a clean set? If you can't, you can't, but you *should*.

Comment: See the second EDIT to the question. Basically if you want to clean `argc` and `argv` from MPI arguments _and_ initialize MPI then use `MPI_Init(argc, argv)`, otherwise `MPI_Init()` is fine (and sometimes it is necessary).

Comment: @gnzlbg: My point is that BillBarth gave you a reasonable explanation (it's now in your second edit), and by being critical without being very constructive, it comes across as argumentative, simply because you didn't like the phrase "why wouldn't you", even though that is not the substance of his answer (which you've accepted is reasonable).

Comment: MPI 2.0 removed the option to implementations to require that argc+argv are those of the C binary - see https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-2.0/node43.htm. So it was still required to be portable in MPI 1.1, unlike the assertion in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd definitely pass them, but i'd pass the pointers like this MPI_init(&argc,&argv), allowing for perfectly valid call MPI_init(NULL,NULL) in your function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's something new in the 3.0 standard that makes it optional in C/C++ to not pass them, but I would definitely pass them. I don't know the current state, but in the past many implementations passed additional command-line arguments to your program when executed and then edited them out in `MPI_Init()`. If you want to use command-line arguments to pass options to your program, if you don't let the implementation do its editing, then you will have to interpret both your arguments and a potentially unknown number and style of arguments from the particular implementation you are using. These arguments are also highly likely to vary from implementation to implementation.

It's pretty normal to call `MPI_Init()` with `argc` and `argv`, so why wouldn't you?

Comment: The spec says that after MPI 1.1 if you pass null to MPI_Init it should read the arguments from the environment. So why pass them to your application in the first place if it can read them from the environment? If runtimes do pass the arguments to the application anyways, then yes it makes sense to call MPI_Init with them such that at least your run-time cleans them before the rest of your application uses them.

Comment: OK, so have you tested every stack available to find out if they have caught up with what they *can* do? If it's possible that some stack might screw up your code's argument parsing by adding extra arguments, why not let it do its part to remove those extra arguments during initialization? What's the harm in passing argc and argv to MPI_Init()? Again, why not do it?

Comment: Also, the MPI implementation can't know at the time it tries to start your code what you're going to pass to MPI_Init, so if it thinks it's going to need to parse them from argv, it had better provide them. It can get the info it needs from the environment if you do pass NULL, but it can't know that when it goes to execute your program.

Comment: You are asking more questions than I do, so I've updated the question a bit.

Comment: (1) I really don't understand your point about the environment info. If i call `mpirun`/`mpiexec` with some parameters, `mpirun` can set some enviroment variables before starting my program, and then read those from within `MPI_Init`. (2) I haven't tested every possible implementation, but as the question states I'm interested only on MPI 3.0 compliant implementations. There aren't a lot of those that are _arcane_.

Comment: (1) Right, but the MPI stack can't know when it invokes your program whether you've called MPI_Init with NULL or with argc and argv. If you've done the latter, then it may fail to init if it does not pass *both* command-line args and env variables. (2) It's still compliant to call with argc and argv, so 3.0 compliant implementations *may* all still be passing arguments on the command line in order to guarantee that MPI_Init() works. I ask again, what is the harm in calling MPI_Init() with argv and argc? If a stack uses the env to pass the necessary info, argv and argc will not be changed...

Comment: ... and if it does use the command line, then you will get clean argc and argv back from MPI_Init()!

Comment: "ask again, what is the harm in calling MPI_Init() with argv and argc?" you tell me, why should I? This is exactly the question: should I or shouldn't I do it, asking me back why shouldn't you is not an answer, and there are good reasons why you shouldn't (in the MPI spec there are some, I've added one as motivation in an EDIT to the question).

Comment: I missed your edit before I typed all of that. My suggestion is to pass argc and argv to the library if it wants to initialize MPI on your behalf. That, or require users to MPI_Init() and pass the library the required communicator. It's possibly unportable not call MPI_Init() with argc and argv. Petsc, for example, supports both styles.

Comment: Supporting both styles seems necessary for anyone writing an MPI wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

The standard recommends (bold mine):

> The MPI standard does not say what a program can do before an MPI_INIT or after an MPI_FINALIZE. In the MPICH implementation, you should do **as little as possible**.

A side effect of the `(argv, argc)` version is that it forces you to put `MPI_Init` in main and not deeper in the call stack.
It is *not fool proof* but it implicitly tells you to put `MPI_Init` very early in `main` and not in a function that can be called twice for example.

I think this is what you have live with for a *runtime* system; it would be better to enforce this at compile-time for example.